# asp.net javascript function wont run

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor-2

I am trying to get a javascript function to run via jquery in an asp.net environment. However no matter what I try the function will not run when the button is clicked. I have tried not using jquery, and making the html input controller id non dynamic. However nothing seems to work. Any help is greatly appreciated, here is the code.

```
@model IEnumerable<NotesWebApp.Models.Product>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div style="height:400px; overflow-y: scroll">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <p>@item.Name</p>
        <p align="center">
            @*
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Note", "AddNote", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Show Notes", "ViewNotes", new { id = item.ID })
            *@
            <input id="@item.ID"type="submit" value="View Notes" class="btn btn-default"/>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
                $("#@item.ID").click(function () {
                    window.alert("Works");
                });
            </script>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="bob" style="display:none">
        <table style="align-items:center" class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Note Text
                </th>
                <th>
                    Create Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var note in item.ProductNotes)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.NoteText)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.CreateDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.Archived)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.Product.Name)
                    </td>
                    @*
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                    </td>*@
                </tr>
            }
            </table>
</div>

}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For page start up code, JQuery calls need to be inside a `$( document ).ready(function() {...}` block for it to work.  Also `<script>...</script>` tags can contain either a src attribute or actual code, *not both*.  Try this:

```
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"/>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#@item.ID").click(function () {
                window.alert("Works");
            })
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: I tried this, doesn't seen to work. I added your suggestions and put the button and script tags outside the razor foreach statement. It worked then. I think this is the problem. But I still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want to use Partial View for each Product item, so that the code will be much more clearer and easily to handle.

Look at [Chapter 8 Sample Code of Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 by Adam Freeman.](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1500/)

For example,

### List

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel

@foreach (var p in Model.Products) {
    @Html.Partial("ProductSummary", p)
}
```

### Partial View

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product

<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@Model.Price.ToString("c")</span>
    </h3>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart")) {
        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to cart" />
        </div>
    }

    <span class="lead"> @Model.Description</span>
</div>

public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int productId, string returnUrl) {
    Product product = repository.Products
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

    if (product != null) {
        GetCart().AddItem(product, 1);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
}
```